# mongodb eval returns zero on failure, how to check if it failed?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, bash, shell

I'm sending some commands to mongodb using `--eval` option as below:

```
mongo --quiet --eval 'printjson("use admin"); printjson(db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } ))'
```

I was trying to check `$?` in my code to check whether the command failed. But it returns `0` even on mongodb errors. How can I check if it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the purpose of the `printjson`?

You don't have to switch to `admin` database for `db.adminCommand`, and `printjson("use admin")` has no effect anyway.

I would do it like this:

```
ret=$( mongo --quiet --eval='db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } ).ok' )
echo $ret
1


ret=$( mongo --quiet --eval='db.adminCommand( { typo_setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } ).ok' )
echo $ret
0
```

Or use

```
ret=$( mongo --quiet --eval='db.adminCommand( { typo_setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } ).errmsg' )
if [[ -z "$ret" ]] ; then
   echo "Success"
else
   echo "Error message: $ret"
fi
```

You get return code =! 0 if the **mongo** fails, the mongo commands have no effect on the return code. Example:

```
mongo "mongodb://admin:WRONG_PASSWORD@localhost" --quiet --eval='db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } ).errmsg'

Error: Authentication failed. :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):3:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1

echo $?
1
```

Comment: Thank you. your answer led me to what I was looking for as: `mongo --quiet --eval 'quit(db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion:  "4.4" } ).ok == 0 ? 1 : 0)'`.